# how to get the first and the last character of a string using a Regex and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get the first and the last letter of a string, using a regex in Javascript and I have no Idea how to achieve this. Anyone has an Idea?

Comment: You can use `String#charAt()`

Comment: this could be a possibility, let's see if anyone can do this with a regex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the comments indicate, it would be very simple to do it without regexp:

```
var str = "This is my string";

var first = str[0];
var last = str[str.length-1];
```

If you really need to use a regexp, you could do it like this:

```
var matches = str.match(/^.|.$/g); // ["T", "g"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just treat the string as an array:

```
text = 'this is a string, hi!';
firstChar = text[0];
lastChar = text[text.length-1];
```

Comment: Right, or if you really don't like the latter form, use `text.slice(-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

if you need regex only :

```
var matches = 'abcde'.match(/^(.).*(.)$/)
console.log(matches)
["abcde", "a", "e"]
```

Comment: dont use a website, just use included console https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console maybe then you can make it work

Comment: Looks nice! Is it possible to 'cut' the 'abcde' so you just get the 'a' 'e' logged?

Comment: yes, the regular expression that @Tibos posted works for this, remember to use the group modificator `/^.|.$/g`